# MAC address and IP address over Cisco and HP switches L2 and L3

Tags: cisco, ip, mac-address, hp

I want to only allow the device that is connected to the switch port with a specific MAC address and a static IP address to access the network. If the device MAC or IP address is changed, it will not be allowed to access the network.

I use the MAC address table, but I also want to restrict the IP address. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are your switches layer-3 switches?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable DHCP snooping, ARP inspection, etc. A host with a statically assigned IP address would need an exception to be manually entered in the switch for the port where the statically address host is connected.

You can also use 802.1X to verify that the host is allowed to connect to the network. This requires more infrastructure than just the switch.

You can also use VACLs to restrict traffic.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it would be port security with sticky option. that way you can learn and remember the first mac address on the port and the port will go down if it detects any other mac address.